# How to model Core Data after CloudKit in iOS app

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, cloudkit

I'm working on setting up Core Data as a local cache of my CloudKit records. I want to model my Core Data models as closely to my CloudKit record types as possible to make converting between the two as easy as possible. As per CloudKit's recommendation, my records are designed with back-references to parent records instead of lists of references for performance reasons but also because I need to support more than CloudKit's 750 references limit. Should I keep this design for my Core Data models or is this not best practice? Thank you.

Comment: I think your confusing best practice with technical limitations. Best practice suggests you model the two as closely as you can. If for technical reasons you cannot then, well you cannot.  That said I would try and come up with a solution that fits both. Get some inspiration from the the dark ages of computing. 8 bit computers needed more bits to be useful, the 8 bits per byte where a serious limitation. Engineers came up with a solution, they create lowest significant byte and the highest significant byte, so so you had 16bits to play with. Use an array of lists.

Comment: @user3069232 I may have worded this question ambiguously. I'm specifically asking if it is *not* best practice to model core data models using back-references. This is best practice for CloudKit https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/CloudKitQuickStart/AddingReferences/AddingReferences.html but I'm not sure if this is best practice for Core Data. I have a working implementation and am not asking for a solution to a technical limitation.